# getting Data from getDefaultSharedPreferences always return empty values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have problem , it's my first time using PreferenceFragment , when I get the data 
it's empty I don't know where is the problem 
here is my PreferenceFragment and strings.xml and settings.xml file 
please help!

**PreferenceFragment**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    private EditTextPreference mEditDomainPrefernce;
    private EditTextPreference mEitDomainPrefernce2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        mEditDomainPrefernce = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("ArabicDomain");


        mEitDomainPrefernce2 = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("KoreanDomain");

        mEitDomainPrefernce2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                mEitDomainPrefernce2.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        mEditDomainPrefernce.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                mEditDomainPrefernce.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

    }


}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string-array name="input">
        <item>English</item>

    </string-array>
    <string-array name="out">
        <item>Arabic</item>
        <item>Korean</item>

    </string-array>
    <string name="default_arabic">http://somelink</string>
    <string name="default_Korean">http://somelink</string>

</resources>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="domain setting">


        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="ArabicDomain"
            android:title="Arabic Domain"
            android:summary="@string/default_arabic"
            android:dialogTitle="change the domain"
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_arabic"
             />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="KoreanDomain"
            android:title="Korean Domain"
            android:summary="@string/default_Korean"
            android:dialogTitle="change the domain"
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_Korean"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>



</PreferenceScreen>
```

**And finally I call the getDefaultSharedPreferences in Activity**

```
 mArabicDomain =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("ArabicDomain","");
        mKoreanDomain = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("KoreanDomain","");
```

and the result both strings are empty please tell me what is wrong

Comment: Try using `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @Vucko same result

Comment: Try using `findPreference("ArabicDomain");` without the `getPreferenceManager()`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument passed to `getDefaultSharedPreferences` corresponds to the defalut value.

> Instead of " " try "some string".

Edit:

Try this:

`sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

`EditTextPreference edp = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("KoreanDomain");`

`sharedPref.getString("KoreanDomain","defValue");`

Comment: How will this help? It will just give that default value, the problem will still pertain since it doesn't write the new value.